# Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query - PHP MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Tengo una tabla donde muestro todas las cabañas que tengo en mi base de datos. Cada una de ellas tendrá su ID, su archivo a modificar (datos de cada cabaña) y un botón "checkbox" para poder seleccionar las que se quieran eliminar.

1) Cuando selecciono uno o varios, y clickeo en "Eliminar", me sale el siguiente error:

`Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\daw\panel_administrador.php on line 96`

2) Deseo que cuando eliminemos las seleccionadas automáticamente se actualice la tabla.

**Código HTML con PHP:**

```
<?php
    require_once "Clases/BD.php";
    require_once "Clases/Cabanas.php";
    require_once "conexion.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();
    //Si existe la sesión "administrador"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
        $administrador = $_SESSION['administrador'];
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Panel del administrador</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sesion_administrador">
            <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
                echo "Bienvenido ".$administrador."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='salir_administrador.php?salir=1'>Salir</a>"; //GET
                //_REQUEST = $_POST o $_GET
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    unset($_SESSION["administrador"]);
                    header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_administrador.php");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="tabla_datos_cabana" id="tabla_datos_cabana" method="POST">
            <div id="mostrar_cabanas">
            <br/><br/><br/>
                <table class="table table-striped" name="tabla" width="600" border="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 10pt">
                    <center>
                        <tr>
                            <thead style="background-color:#A9F5A9">
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>ID Cabaña</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"250\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Nombre</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Modificar</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Eliminar</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                            </thead>
                        </tr>   
                        <?php
                        $datos = BD::obtenerCabanas();
                        foreach($datos as $cabana){
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>".$cabana->getIdcabana()."</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"250\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>".$cabana->getNombre()."</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>"?> 
                                    <a href="modificar.php?idcabana=<?=$cabana->getIdcabana();?>">
                                        <img src="imagenes/modificar.png" height='24' width='26' onmouseover="this.src='imagenes/modificar_in.png';" onmouseout="this.src='imagenes/modificar.png';">
                                    </a> <?php "</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><center><input type='checkbox' name='marcados[]' id='marcados[]' value=".$cabana->getIdcabana()."></center>";
                         echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </center>
                </table>

                <!-- Botón NUEVA cabaña -->
                <div class="boton_anadir" class="table-responsive" align="left">
                    <font face="verdana">
                        <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="nueva_cabana" id="nueva_cabana" value="Añadir cabaña"></b>
                    </font><br/>
                </div>

                <!-- Botón ELIMINAR cabaña/s -->
                <div class="boton_eliminar" class="table-responsive" align="left">
                    <font face="verdana">
                        <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="eliminar_cabanas" id="eliminar_cabanas" onclick="return confirm('¿Deseas realmente eliminar estas cabañas?');" value="Eliminar cabañas"></b>
                    </font><br/>
                </div>

                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "Eliminar cabañas"...
                if(isset($_POST['eliminar_cabanas'])){
                    if(empty($_POST['marcados'])){
                        echo "<h4><center>No se ha seleccionado ninguna cabaña.</center></h4>";
                    }else{
                        foreach($_POST['marcados'] as $valor){
                            $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
                            $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana=".$valor);
                            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                        }
                        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL=panel_administrador.php\">";
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana=".$valor);`
                            `$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);`

Comment: Porque repites dos veces mysqli_query?

Comment: En el primero hacer `$sql` y guardas mysql_query y luego vuelves y lo ejecutas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) espera como parámetros la conexión y luego la `Query` es decir un `String` y lo que le está pasando es un valor booleano `TRUE` O `FALSE` que son los posibles valores de retorno de [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php)

```
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana=".$valor);//retorna true o false
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); // error
```

Lo anterior es el posible fallo para que muestre el mensaje de error. Pero además está mezclando dos extensiones del lenguaje, `MYSQL` que se recomienda dejar de usar por motivos de que fue declarada obsoleta y `MySQLI` que la emplea pero de forma insegura al pasar directamente los parámetros concatenados. Sería mejor emplear consultas preparadas [Pregunta y Respuestas sobre este tema.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Ejemplo

```
$mysqli = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $valor);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes, se encuentra en esta sección:

```
94    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
95    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana=".$valor);
96    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
```

### Primero

Realizas la conexion, hasta aqui todo bien

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
```

### Pero

En esta parte encontramos un pequeño detalle:

```
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana=".$valor);
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
```

Guardas un valor en la variable `$sql`, que para este caso, es lo que retorne `[mysql_query()][1]`.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana=".$valor);
```

Esto te retornara algo que en PHP se conoce como un valor `[mixed][1]`, lo cual deja de ser una cadena.

Luego, estas pasando ciertos parametros a la función `[mysqli_query()][1]`, la cual como segundo parametro recibe un texto, mas no un valor el resultado de otra función.

```
mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
```

### Solucion

Organiza el codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
$sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana='%d'", $valor);

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
```

Puedes hacer uso de la funcion [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php), para agregar variables usando modificadores.

Comment: Cuando edites finalmente la pregunta lo leeré.

Comment: dame un segundo :)

Comment: Ya te lo explico

Comment: Ya te he agregado un ejemplo

Comment: @omaza1990 He hecho la explicacion, cualquier duda, no dudes en preguntarme

Comment: Funciona correctamente. No conocía la función "sprintf", por eso en mi mysqli encadené la consulta con el $valor.

Comment: @omaza1990 Si, pues una manera es con sprintf, pero igual solo puedes concatenarlo, ya he agregado enlaces para hacer mas amena la consulta de referencias (y)

Comment: @omaza1990 Si te sirvio, no olvides aceptarla :)

Comment: @IvanBotero "pero igual solo puedes concatenarlo" **No** , soluciona un problema su respuesta pero genera uno aún mayor. _(Inseguridad)_ :)

Comment: @Dev.Joel Puede que tengas razon, pero en ese caso apliqué el principio KISS, di solucion solo a lo que exactamente el OP solicitaba, pero igual, gracias por el comentario.